# How to troubleshoot Buildozer's Error type 3: Activity Class {} does not exist

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to push a Kivy app into Android for testing but getting:

```
Starting: Intent { act=org.kivy.android.PythonActivity cmp=org.test.trackerwars/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.test.trackerwars/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} does not exist.
```

I've looked through topics on this problem where people were advising to delete gradle cache which I did but that didn't help. Other topics speak about non-updated data in the file below.

This is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Replace org.libsdl.app with the identifier of your game below, e.g.
 com.gamemaker.game
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.test.trackerwars"
  android:versionCode="721100"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="auto">

<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"

        android:xlargeScreens="true"

/>

<!-- Android 2.3.3 -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<!-- OpenGL ES 2.0 -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<!-- Allow writing to external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />






<!-- Create a Java class extending SDLActivity and place it in a
     directory under src matching the package, e.g.
        src/com/gamemaker/game/MyGame.java

     then replace "SDLActivity" with the name of your class (e.g. "MyGame")
     in the XML below.

     An example Java class can be found in README-android.txt
-->
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
             android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >



    <meta-data android:name="wakelock" android:value="0"/>

    <activity android:name="org.test.trackerwars"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"

              android:launchMode="singleTask"

              >


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.test.trackerwars.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="org.test.trackerwars.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>


</application>
```

I made sure package name is identical to the line with Android name in Activities. That didn't help either. Still the same error. I can't even test my app because of this. What should I try ?

Comment: What happens if you run the app from the device?

Comment: Well, nothing because the app never made it into the phone. Buildozer is a packaging software. Without it the app will never be packaged into apk file which Android recognizes. The packaging process crashes on the above error.

Comment: The above error is with the `run` part of the buildozer command, not the `deploy`.

Comment: OK so I used `buildozer android deploy` without `run` at the end and it gave me apk file in the `bin` directory. Error output in terminal says `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`

Comment: I shouldn't be getting this error as Buildozer is responsible for fetching correct SDK.

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting the error, it doesn't refer to the SDK version used to build the app. What android version does the device have, is it older than api 21?

Comment: @inclement  It's Android 4.4.3  I intent to test it on Nexus 5. The codename is Jelly Bean I believe.

Comment: I'm afraid that is too old for p4a, we only support api 21+, which corresponds to Android 5 or higher. See https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers

Comment: We ? Are you one of core devs of p4a ? I've got another phone running Android 8. That could work.

Comment: @inclement  It worked on Android 8 ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @inclement for point out the fact that I was trying to deploy the app to outdated Android version. Deployment succeeded as soon as I used more recent Android.

Answer (score 0):

you can go around this trouble by using:

```
buildozer --verbose android deploy
```

this would directly install the app on your phone. assuming you have been able to get your phone be detected by virtual box and have USB Debugging turned on in the "developer options" in the setting of your device. although, it doesnt create an apk.

if you want an apk, run this:

```
buildozer --verbose android debug
```